# subract two nested dictionaries python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, hashmap

i have two nested dict

```
{'BTC': {'DAE': -10526, 'Vega': 186, 'Theta': -34, 'Gamma': 149674},
 'ETH': {'DAE': -1123, 'Vega': 57, 'Theta': -5, 'Gamma': 2257}}
```

and

```
{'BTC': {'DAE': -105126, 'Vega': 1186, 'Theta': -314, 'Gamma': 1419674},
 'ETH': {'DAE': -11213, 'Vega': 157, 'Theta': -15, 'Gamma': 22157}}
```

Want to get subracted dict values. Getting the same with for loop. but any other way other than forloop.

Comment: What do you define as subtraction here? Is it subtracting all the values in matching keys? Is it removing keys that  match and keeping those that don't? Is it doing either of the above for the nested component? There's enough ambiguity in your statement that Python likely doesn't provide a function to do this for you - you'll be best off writing the function yourself.

Comment: Subract values from the dict, like a general subraction only

Comment: I think he means taking out the values from first one which are present in second one. For better understanding @Madan should give expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want `d1 - d2`.

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
out = {k1: {k2: v2-d2[k1][k2] for k2,v2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in d1.items()}
```

And if there is a chance that not all values are present in `d2`:

```
out = {k1: {k2: v2-d2.get(k1, {}).get(k2, 0) for k2,v2 in v1.items()}
       for k1, v1 in d1.items()}
```

Or with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.DataFrame(d1).sub(pd.DataFrame(d2)).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'BTC': {'DAE': 94600, 'Vega': -1000, 'Theta': 280, 'Gamma': -1270000},
 'ETH': {'DAE': 10090, 'Vega': -100, 'Theta': 10, 'Gamma': -19900}}
```

Reproducible input:

```
d1 = {'BTC': {'DAE': -10526, 'Vega': 186, 'Theta': -34, 'Gamma': 149674},
      'ETH': {'DAE': -1123, 'Vega': 57, 'Theta': -5, 'Gamma': 2257}}

d2 = {'BTC': {'DAE': -105126, 'Vega': 1186, 'Theta': -314, 'Gamma': 1419674},
      'ETH': {'DAE': -11213, 'Vega': 157, 'Theta': -15, 'Gamma': 22157}}
```